# jQuery UI Date Picker: Displaying a 5-digit year in <select>

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Im not looking to solve the deca-millennium bug (which will come into effect in about 8,000 years ;)) but I *do* want to display the 5-digit year to the users of the date-picker widget (which rocks, btw).

e.g. 02005, 03013. Here is a screenshot: https://img.skitch.com/20110527-8jxrgcnaiugf394ig7yy647111.png

And here is the what I *think* is the JavaScript file in question: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js but maybe the display stuff is elsewhere?

Comment: Now *that's* forwards compatibility.

Comment: I guess I could also do it after the fact, outside of jQuery UI and post-apply the prefix, not sure how tho.

Comment: Most programmers would shrug this off and say "eh...I'm not going to be here in 8,000 years, not my problem."  Oh wait, that is not what you're trying to solve....but still.

Answer (score 0):

w00t. Solved.

Since this is just a visual hack, it was pretty easy, but my fix has also got my locked in to my own, modified version of the file :-. Not Cool but the line in question is https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js#L1617 `s/'>'/'>0'`.

It would still be great to figure out a more portable solution.